# How to use WSDL2Java generated files?

Tags: java, wsdl, apache-axis, wsdl2java

I generated the .java files using wsdl2java found in axis2-1.5. Now it generated the files in this folder structure: src/net/mycompany/www/services/

The files in the services folder are: SessionIntegrationStub and SessionIntegrationCallbackHandler.

I would like to consume the webservice now. I added the net folder to the CLASSPATH environment variable. My java file now imports the webservice using:

```
import net.mycompany.www.services;

public class test 
{ 
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    SessionIntegrationStub stub = new SessionIntegrationStub();
    System.out.println(stub.getSessionIntegration("test"));
  } 
}
```

Now when I try to compile this using:

javac test.java

I get: package net.mycompany.www does not exist.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

As already suggested you need to import the generated stub class, not it's package

```
import net.mycompany.www.services.SessionIntegrationStub;
```

You then need to populate your XML request objects. I don't know what your WSDL looks like but for example

```
SessionIntegrationStub.SessionRequest req = new SessionIntegrationStub.SessionRequest()
req.setParamOne(1)
req.setParamTwo(2)
```

And finally invoke the web service

```
SessionIntegrationStub.SessionResponse resp = stub.operationOne(req)

println resp.getAnswer()
```

**Note**: The setters and getters above correspond to elements declared in your schema. The SessionRequest and SessionResponse classes would correspond to complex types declared in your schema.

Answer (score 0):

This should presumably say `import net.mycompany.www.services.*;`. You missed the asterisk.

Comment: I tried that. However now it cant find the generated stub. My header looks like this now: package net.mycompany.www.services; import net.mycompany.services.* where the current file is in the services folder.

Answer (score 0):

Issue here is your package structure. Your test.java is in different package then your generated source.

You need to keep current file in same package structure or provide full path of your generated source in javac like

javac src/net/mycompany/www/services/*.java src/net/mycompany/services/*.java